# Testing the user interface inside a program running on Linux

Tags: python, user-interface, testing

Are there libraries for automating (using Python) the management of a program run by a user on a Linux operating system?

I need to create tests to test the program interface (pressing buttons, entering text in special fields, reading text from the program window).

UPD:

`pywinauto` - as I understand it, this library is only suitable for managing Windows applications

UPD2:
The application that needs to be managed works on the basis of Visual Studio, maybe I can somehow connect to it using selenium?

Comment: without more details given; see https://github.com/autokey/autokey ?

Comment: @rasjani It does not allow you to get text from an open program window and in fact just performs clicks on certain coordinates